# Best practice for filing of abstract class and subclasses?

Tags: php

I was wondering what is the best (and real-word) practice for doing an abstract class and subclasses in PHP when it comes to filing.

I have `abstract class games`, and I was wondering if I should put the subclasses into separate files and `require_once('games.class.php');` for separate files or just have each subclass in the `abstract class games` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

People generally tend to use **one file per class** -- mapping the files names to the classes names *(this facilitates [autoloading](https://www.php.net/autoload))*.

For a quite good example of this, you should take a look to the sources of [**Zend Framework**][2] : there are a great number of classes, with interfaces, abstract classes, multiple-levels of sub-directories and all.

And here is the relevant part of their [**Coding Standards**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I super appreciate this!

Comment: Question regarding the autoloading. I was looking at the Zend Framework, and can't really figure it out. They use require_once in the classes themselves. Where do I put `__autoload`?

For example I have `/classes/games.class.php`, and say `classes/games/xbox.class.php` this xbox class should `require_once 'classes/games.class.php'` and should I use `require_once '../games.class.php'` or the previous?

__autoload seems like it should be in a **header.php** file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using autoloading instead of require or include and of course one file per class.

Answer (score 0):

you accomplish this in a more future-proof manner you would definately stick to 'one class per file'.

The actual classes could then be included via many ways amongst which the autoloader.
One tip: Just name the file/class accordingly:

```
abstract class GamesAbstract {}
```

```
class Games extends GamesAbstract {}
```